# node project not load modules

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js

I pulled project from git, and then ran `npm install`, which didn't make a mistake, and ran `npm run dev` after installation

remaind me `npm install --save ~plugins/utils ~plugins/axios`

But these two documents are my own two packaging, certainly does not need install ah, and installed all the dependencies are not.

But all dependencies can be found under node_module, and I don't know what the problem is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S6EX.png)

Comment: Could you please add the text of the error instead of an image? Or a higher resolution image? It's very hard to read.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is always advised to add code instead of images of the code. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit the question accordingly to get better answers.

Comment: and share your nuxt.config.js ;-) Your plugins should be declare with this syntax:   plugins: ['~plugins/utils', '~plugins/axios']

Answer (score 0):

They made a change on nuxt since rc3, now you have to import `'~/plugins/axios'` not `'~plugins/axios'`, do the same with components